# NGINX: using multiple node as load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, load-balancing

I have application deployed on tomcat server on machine A,B,C,D
I want to load balance using the Nginx using two load balancer nodes LB1 & LB2.
All configuration I got is using only one node as load balancer.

is it possible using Nginx.

If we have a critical application running on server require the zero down time. If we go with one LB and for some reason LB itself fails,then there will be an issue.

We have this set up initially using AWS Load balancer, but recently we start using the websockets. The web sockets are not working correctly on EC2 load balancer.

if some one has better option please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Use Amazon ELB and forward TCP:80/443 instead of HTTP:80/443

The only downside of balancing TCP is that your appservers have to deliver SSL certificates themselves if you use HTTPS.

If you want to run the loadbalancer yourself without having a single point of failure you can use haproxy to fall back to a standby machine when the primary balancer fails.

http://www.loadbalancer.org/blog/transparent-load-balancing-with-haproxy-on-amazon-ec2